# Sort by string weight by java

Tags: java, algorithm

Write a java program to sort a string array in descending order based upon their weight.
Weight of string can be calculated in the following way
letter `A` has weight `1` and letter a has weight `-1`.Likewise letter `Z` has weight `26` and letter `z` has `-26`.

so the weight of string `Java` will be `-14`.(J=10,a=-1,v=-22,a=-1)
Hence sort the array in descending order based upon the weight.

Sample Input:

```
3
Python Java HTML
```

Sample Output:

```
Java Python HTML
```

Note if two strings have same weight then print the one which is entered first in the array

Comment: What have you tried so far and why did it not work? Also, is this a homework related question?

Comment: I am a beginner ,i Tried but coudnt able to get the logic..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "give me the code" question.

Comment: @ganesh Show your tried codes.

Comment: The people here will help you only to get the code right, but not with completing your work from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Java is an Object Oriented Language, so use it. Also it is obviously your homework and you don't do anything at all, so I'm just gonna give you a hint:

```
create an object with Strings, their weights and their position in the array.

sort objects bases on their weights and, for equal weight, position in array.

print sorted objects Strings.
```

Comment: +1 for providing a hint by breaking the problem down into smaller problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is

1. *Read* all the data given and put it into an apropriate *collection*
2. *Sort* the collection. In OO languages like Java we usually implement a `Comparator`
3. *Output* the results: *foreach* loop is a better thing to do it

The skeleton could be something like that:

```
 // Comparer to implement your algorithm of comparing two strings
 class MyComparer implements Comparator<String> {
   @Override
   public int compare(String left, String right) {
     //TODO: return -1 if left < right; 0 if left == right and 1 if left > right
   }
 }

 ...

 // Stage 1:
 ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

 //TODO: put user input into the collection

 // Stage 2:
 Collections.sort(items, new MyComparer());

 // Stage 3:
 for(String item: items) {
   //TODO: Print out item in a right format      
 }
```